# Cakephp redirection calls root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

Okay so i have the project folder called `MyProject`

This project contains cake.

Now i have a controller called UsersController and in this example i want to access the Action called login.

so when i go to the following site: `localhost/MyProject/cake/users/login`

I get the following error:

```
'/MyProject/cake/app/webroot/index.php/MyProject/cake/users/login'
```

As far as i can see it goes into webroot and then try to go to the root of my folder again to find the right url. But i have NO idea why its doing this.

Here are the releveant files:

**Cake folder**

**.htaccess**

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Requests collector.
 *
 *  This file collects requests if:
 *  - no mod_rewrite is available or .htaccess files are not supported
 *  - requires App.baseUrl to be uncommented in app/Config/core.php
 *  - app/webroot is not set as a document root.
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

/**
 *  Get Cake's root directory
 */
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);

/**
 * This only needs to be changed if the "cake" directory is located
 * outside of the distributed structure.
 * Full path to the directory containing "cake". Do not add trailing directory separator
 */
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
}

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

**App folder:**

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

**index.php:**

```
   <?php
/**
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.10.0.1076
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

**webroot FOLDER:**

**.htaccess**

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/admin$ index.php/dashboards [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Index
 *
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.webroot
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
/**
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
/**
 * These defines should only be edited if you have cake installed in
 * a directory layout other than the way it is distributed.
 * When using custom settings be sure to use the DS and do not add a trailing DS.
 */

/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
//    define('ROOT', DS . 'home' . DS . 'me');
}
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
//    define ('APP_DIR', 'bloglic-2013');
}

/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 * Un-comment this line to specify a fixed path to CakePHP.
 * This should point at the directory containing `Cake`.
 *
 * For ease of development CakePHP uses PHP's include_path.  If you
 * cannot modify your include_path set this value.
 *
 * Leaving this constant undefined will result in it being defined in Cake/bootstrap.php
 */
    //define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');

/**
 * Editing below this line should NOT be necessary.
 * Change at your own risk.
 *
 */
if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
    define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}
if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
    define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
}

// for built-in server
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);
}

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
    }
    if (!include ('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
} else {
    if (!include (CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
}
if (!empty($failed)) {
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}

App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse());
```

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not really understanding how RewriteRules works.

When you try to access the URL `http://localhost/MyProject/cake/users/login` the RewriteRule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
    ...
</IfModule>
```

is redirecting everything right after your base URL (in this case `http://localhost`) to `index.php` and is appending it there.

That's why you're getting this error. What you want to do is to access the site like this:

```
http://localhost/users/login
```

In the "background" the webserver is executing this URL like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php/users/login
```

and is calling the according route.

PS: The 'error message' you posted is not really an error message and I assume that the error is that which I tried to explain to you here.

Comment: so what can i do to fix the issue? :S

Comment: Try opening the URL http://localhost/users/login and check if it works as expected.

Comment: The requested URL /users/login was not found on this server.

Comment: btw note that if i go to localhost/MyProject/cake/index.php/users/login there is no problem at all